# SMS andrio studio permission issue

Tags: android, permissions, sms

so,  I have this SMS application in android studio. When running this first time it pop:ed up a window asking for permission and so the SMS got sent. But later on it never asks for permissions and the SMS dosent send. Can anyone help me?

this is my main class.

```
package com.example.xbhatti.sms4;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS =0 ;
Button sendBtn;
EditText txtphoneNo;
EditText txtMessage;
String phoneNo;
String message;

@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
        }
    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
    txtphoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendSMSMessage();
        }
    });
}



protected void sendSMSMessage() {
    phoneNo = txtphoneNo.getText().toString();
    message = txtMessage.getText().toString();

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
        }
    }
}


}
```

and this is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.xbhatti.sms4.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sending SMS Example"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Tutorials point "
    android:textColor="#ff87ff09"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageButton" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:hint="Enter Phone Number"
    android:phoneNumber="true"
    android:textColorHint="@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText"
    android:textColorHint="@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageButton"
    android:hint="Enter SMS" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send Sms"
    android:id="@+id/btnSendSMS"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my mainfest xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.xbhatti.sms4">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From SDK 23 and onwards, permissions are requested in real-time and once granted they will not be requested again.

Therefore, I think this is your problem. There is no else statement if the permission is already granted which would be to send the sms.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
            }
    } else {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

**Reference**
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: i have an else statement in method onRequest() . Where should i place this code?

Comment: If you see my code above you can see that i already have this code

Comment: I have updated my answer, can you check the code if it works. If it does work, you would also have to check it in SDK below 23.

Comment: do you know if there is a way to send sms to several numbers`?

Comment: I have not used SmsManager but in general you can have a list containing your numbers and then loop through the list and send the smses one at a time. You could also refactor the sms code to a function so that it is cleaner to call.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean haveSendSMSPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (getApplicationContext().checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getApplicationContext() , new String[]{Manifest.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 1);
            return false;
        }
    }else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Just use this Method when your app start

Comment: I am getting this error :                 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getApplicationContext() , new String[]{Manifest.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 1);
I am getting red here.

Comment: If you are in fragment then you have use `getActivity()` instead of `getApplicationContex()`

Comment: do you know if there is a way to send sms to several numbers`?

Answer (score 0):

the issue is now solved. 
I just had to add.

```
                  SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

in sendSMS()